# what should I do if I want to set the default value of my parameter if the parameter has null value

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How to set the default value of the variable `valueC` if the `valueC` is `null`, and then get the default value for `valueC = 100` in  elvis operator.

```
// Here my full code 

fun main() {
    val valueA = 65
    val valueB = 52
    val valueC = 78

    val result = calculate(valueA, valueB, valueC)

    // TODO 3
    println("Result is $result")
}

fun calculate(valueA: Int, valueB: Int, valueC: Int?=100): String {
    // TODO 1
    val result = valueC?.let { valueA + (valueB - valueC) } ?: 100
    return generateResult(result)
}

// TODO 2
fun generateResult(result: Int) = result.toString()
```

Comment: TODO 1:
Complete the initialization of the result variable by performing a mathematical operation on the argument given with the following calculation formula:
valueA + (valueB - valueC)
If valueC is null, give 100 for the default value.

TODO 2:
Complete the code to return the value in the form of text that will later be printed on the console.

TODO 3:
Add code to print the value of the result variable.

Answer (score 1):

> If valueC is null, give 100 for the default value.

You can use the elvis operator when you use `valueC` in any expression:

```
fun calculate(valueA: Int, valueB: Int, valueC: Int?): String {
    val result = valueA + (valueB - (valueC ?: 100))
    return generateResult(result)
}
```

or shadow the `valueC` name, setting the new variable to a default value if `valueC` is `null` or leave the original value otherwise:

```
fun calculate(valueA: Int, valueB: Int, valueC: Int?): String {
    val valueC = valueC ?: 100

    val result = valueA + (valueB - valueC)
    return generateResult(result)
}
```

Comment: `fun main() {
    val valueA = 65
    val valueB = 52
    val valueC = 78

    val result = calculate(valueA, valueB, valueC)

    // TODO 3
    println()
}

fun calculate(valueA: Int, valueB: Int, valueC: Int?): String {
    // TODO 1
    val result = 0
    return generateResult(result)
}

// TODO 2
fun generateResult(result: Int) = ""`

Comment: that's the original todo task

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin supports default arguments in function declarations. You can specify a default value for a function parameter. The default value is used when the corresponding argument is omitted from the function call.

```
fun displayGreeting(message: String, name: String = "Guest") {
  println("Hello $name, $message")
}


displayGreeting("Welcome to the CalliCoder Blog", "John") // Hello John, Welcome to the CalliCoder Blog
```

However, If you omit the argument that has a default value from the function call, then the default value is used in the function body -

```
displayGreeting("Welcome to the CalliCoder Blog") // Hello Guest, Welcome to the CalliCoder Blog
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter should be like this

```
calculate(valueA: Int, valueB: Int, valueC: Int =100)  
// if valuec is null 100 is the default value of C
```

full sample program

```
fun main() {
//without param c value
println(calculate(5,10))      //output -85
 // with param c value
println(calculate(5,10,5))     //output 10

}

fun calculate(valueA: Int, valueB: Int, valueC: Int =100): String {
val result = valueC?.let { valueA + (valueB - it) }
return generateResult(result)
}



fun generateResult(result:Int):String
{
return result.toString()
}
```

Comment: `valueC` isn't nullable so the `valueC?.let { }` call is redundant.

Comment: I need to pass all of the test requirement, the requirement was like this 

TODO 1:
Complete the initialization of the result variable by performing a mathematical operation on the argument given with the following calculation formula:
valueA + (valueB - valueC)
If valueC is null, give 100 for the default value.

TODO 2:
Complete the code to return the value in the form of text that will later be printed on the console.

Comment: I still get rejected on your solution

Comment: Yes @jsamol valueC?.let { } is no need

Comment: did you post all those thing when your post the questions? think your self?